# Nuxt error vue.reactive is not a function

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I needed to make some upgrades in my Next application. As I run yarn upgrade package@x.x.x I got an error:

> vue.reactive is not a function.

I did not know what to do with it so I reverted the changes to their original state. But the error is still there although all packages are the same as before. Compilation is successfully done but the browser shows the same error.

How can I get back to the original state? I'm using [vuex-stores](https://github.com/ElMassimo/vuex-stores/issues/19).

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update: locking the Vuex version in the `package.json` should solve the issue here.

---

Try to clean the cache of your package manager (`yarn cache clean -all`), delete the `node_modules` + delete the `yarn.lock` and run `yarn` back.

Checking differences with git could also be useful. Setting the **exact** version of the package in the `package.json` could also be helpful.

Comment: I found the problem. Here it is https://github.com/ElMassimo/vuex-stores/issues/19 But I am not so skilled to be sure. Am I right this causes that error? I that case new installetion will alway pull this BC break version.

Comment: @Čamo this should still be using Vuex3 so it should not be the issue so far.

Comment: No it uses Vuex 4.0.2.

Comment: Ok I lock the Vuex on version 3. Many thanks for help.